# OpenCV - cvCreateTrackbar()

Tags: c++, string, opencv, char

If you see `cvCreateTrackbar()` from: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html

If you look at the function signature:

```
int cvCreateTrackbar(const char* trackbarName, const char* windowName, int* value, int count, CvTrackbarCallback onChange)
```

It describes for example the function parameter `trackbarName` as follows:

```
trackbarName – Name of the created trackbar.
```

In the `Learning OpenCV` book, it had the following function signature:

```
cvCreateTrackbar("Position","Example3",&g_slider_position,frames,onTrackSlide);
```

`trackbarName` as we see is a pointer to a `char`, and thus has to hold an address as its value. How come we are passing `"position"` as an argument? And, isn't `"position"` a `string`, how can we pass that to a `char`?

Thanks.

Comment: `printf()` accepts a `const char*` too, but everyone passes a literal string like `printf("blah blah")`, have you thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

"Position" is a `const char*` - a literal C string. It is a pointer to an array or `char`s!